# yii2 grid view it possible to not export all columns?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

[image]I don't want to export all columns from grid view.I need few of them to export to excel sheet only.

Is it possible in yii2 grid view?

Comment: what GridView are you using? can you add some code?

Comment: Above I have edited the post.I want just a few of them to export to excel sheet.

Comment: if you are using kartik gird (i can't tell from just the screenshot), you have an `hideFromExport` option on each column (see [docs](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#data-column))

Comment: 'hiddenFromExport' => true (in your column)